# What is the fastest algorithm to solve a Nonlinear second order differential equation numerically

Tags: computational-physics, numerical-method

I am trying to solve a second order non linear differential equation in one variable. Using RK4 I am getting good accuracy and is working fine.

But the problem is my range is very high so it will take years to complete if I use it straight.

I am coding in Octave, I was told shifting to C can save some time. I would also like to get some guidance over this, but that alone won't solve my problem.

I am searching for some alternative so that I can get the job done faster

Thanking in Advance

Comment: That's not a physics question, but might be appropriate for [scicomp.SE].

Comment: Can you increase the step size?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Agreed, but physicists probably come across this specific situation more often. I personally do almost nothing but solve non-linear second-order coupled PDEs using the RK4 method. So maybe we can offer more insight

Comment: The best guidance one could give would be to do what you can in C and Google for help when needed.

Comment: Could you tell us the generic form of your ODE that you're trying to solve? It will help if I know that in order for me to give an answer.

Comment: There is no magic single algorithm. Stability, accuracy, and speed all seem mutually incompatible as well.  As for language, that may invoke holy wars - most languages now have libraries based on long standing, well debugged C or Fortran code.

Comment: If it is ODE you should use ODEINT. It is a highly optimized ODE solver library for C++ and you can change your integration algorithm by just changing one word.

Comment: The recommendations to use existing libraries is sound. I would just add that most of the time, you know a thing or two about your function - like, how much curvature there is. If the range is large, there are most likely areas where the curvature (higher order derivatives) is small; in those areas you can afford larger step sizes. If you spend a bit of time figuring out what the right "next step" is, instead of using the smallest step you need everywhere, you can shave a lot of time off. Of course there are other tricks (preallocation, vectorization etc) that speed up Octave.

Comment: Floris suggestion of adaptive step size can increase both accuracy and speed. I want to add that ODEINT also supports that.

Comment: Also SciPy has an interface for it so you can have a performance similar to C++ in the comfort of Python.

Comment: @JimtheEnchanter Still. The specifics of the question are better off in math.se (numerical-mathematics). At least the algorithmic part. Floris answer is the most sound here, first check your function - then look for a method. RK4(5) is the jack-of-all-trades as a method, some of its implementations use an adaptive step-size, too.

Answer (score 1):

[Bulirsch–Stoer like algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulirsch%E2%80%93Stoer_algorithm) may work better than the Runge-Kutta like methods here. You can consider any arbitrary scheme for approximating the function at the next time step, but instead of modeling the deviation as a function of the time step $h$ by power series, you consider the asymptotic behavior valid for large $h$. A rational function approximation typically works quite well. You then can use that to extrapolate the approximations to zero $h$.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I can think of that can improve run times (outside of using a compiled language like C/C++ or Fortran).

1. Use a hybrid RK2 + RK4/5 integration method.
   Here, you use an RK2 method first and test the truncation error. If it's sufficiently small, accept the value & move on. If the error is too large, move to an [adaptive 4-5 RK method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods#Adaptive_Runge.E2.80.93Kutta_methods) (or higher order).
2. If you are not using it already, consider the [implicit method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods#Implicit_Runge.E2.80.93Kutta_methods):$$y^{n+1}=y^{n}+f\left(t^n+h,y^{n+1}\right)$$
   Stability is not usually an issue, which allows for a larger time step $h$.